# Stacked Bar Chart with a bar showing the forecasted quantity and the real quantity as the part of this bar

Tags: charts

I was looking for a way to make a stacked bar chart, where a bar shows the forecast  and the real quantity as the part of the forecast.
So, if the forecasted quantity is 10 and the real quantity is 5, then the bar height should be 10. Instead, it makes it 15, so adds up one quantity to another.
Is there a way to proceed other than making additional calculations (such as calculating forecasted quantity minus real quantity and using the results instead of initial forecasted quantity?).

Comment: You could use the ChartLayout option "Overlapped" rather than "Stacked" but the larger one will obscure the smaller one if the data isn't properly ordered.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use Associations for the data, Overlapped doesn't obscure the smaller.  Such as this: BarChart[{Association@{"forecast" -> 10, "actual" -> 5}, 
  Association@{"forecast" -> 30, "actual" -> 10}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Overlapped"]

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: I used data from @kglr and my statement about using an association to make the data visible is wrong.  Use the method below to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

If we use the option setting `ChartLayout -> "Overlapped"`, some bars may become invisible:

```
data = {{10, 5}, {5, 10}, {15, 8}, {8, 12}};
colors = {Blue, Yellow};
legendlabels = {"actual", "forecast"};

BarChart[data, 
 ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", 
 ChartStyle -> colors,
 ChartLegends -> legendlabels]
```

[image]

To make all bars visible we can use the approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192892/125) to define a function to pre-process input data into a form so that all bars are visible in `BarChart` output:

```
ClearAll[reArrange]
reArrange[dat_, cols_] := Map[SortBy[-First @ # &]]@
   Transpose @ MapThread[Thread @* Style, {Transpose @ dat, cols}];

datamodified = reArrange[data, colors];
BarChart[datamodified, 
 ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[colors, legendlabels]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution but the color overlap seems slightly confusing.  Perhaps using opacity for color helps make this more obvious.  Such as this: colors = {Opacity[.5, Blue], Opacity[.5, Yellow]};  But this is just an opinion.

Comment: @MarkR, using opacity is  a good idea.